# How to create multimodal data set?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, multimodal

I want to make music recommendation system based on multimodal dataset. Ive been looking for publicly available dataset but I couldn't find it anywhere . I want to know where will I get multimodal dataset for music or book ?
I watched many YOUTUBE videos but didn't find any video where they are teaching how to create multimodal dataset.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by multimodal? Could you clarify? When it comes to music Spotify has an API to retrieve features of artists/music (like tempo). There’s also the musicbrainz dataset https://musicbrainz.org/

Comment: Multimodal means structured and unstructured data. so our features would include textual data as well as image data (images of album). Use of multimodal data will improve efficiency of our recommendation system. @nablag

Comment: That's a bit of a tough one. Have you heard of web scraping? Maybe what you could do is scrape lyrical data from websites and combine it with other datasets?

Comment: Hi, were you able to make a multimodal dataset? I'm working on a similar problem right now. I want to make a dataset with image and general tabular data. But I'm unsure as to how to make it